# Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pi3+ +ubuntu mate 18.04 + ros melodic

I don't know how to fix this error.

I  just want run hector slam with rplidar. Plz  help, thank you

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.15", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.15") 
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.17
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 14 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - hector_slam (metapackage)
-- ~~  - hector_slam_launch
-- ~~  - hector_map_tools
-- ~~  - hector_nav_msgs
-- ~~  - hector_geotiff
-- ~~  - hector_geotiff_plugins
-- ~~  - hector_marker_drawing
-- ~~  - hector_compressed_map_transport
-- ~~  - rplidar_ros
-- ~~  - hector_imu_attitude_to_tf
-- ~~  - hector_imu_tools
-- ~~  - hector_map_server
-- ~~  - hector_trajectory_server
-- ~~  - hector_mapping
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'hector_slam'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_slam)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_slam_launch'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_slam_launch)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_map_tools'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_map_tools)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_nav_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_nav_msgs)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- hector_nav_msgs: 0 messages, 5 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_geotiff'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_geotiff)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_geotiff_plugins'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_geotiff_plugins)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_marker_drawing'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_marker_drawing)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_compressed_map_transport'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_compressed_map_transport)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rplidar_ros'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rplidar_ros)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_imu_attitude_to_tf'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy


CMake Error at /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/share/tf2/cmake/tf2Config.cmake:113 (message):
  Project 'tf2' specifies '/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/geometry2/tf2/include'
  as an include dir, which is not found.  It does neither exist as an
  absolute directory nor in
  '/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/geometry2/tf2//home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/geometry2/tf2/include'.
  Check the website 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf2' for information and
  consider reporting the problem.


Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/tf2_ros/cmake/tf2_rosConfig.cmake:174 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/tf/cmake/tfConfig.cmake:174 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  hector_slam/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:698: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322397/invoking-%22make-cmake_check_build_system%22-failed/) by [Red](https://answers.ros.org/users/41243/red/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you cloned the package https://github.com/ros/geometry2 in your ws. I think if you haven't installed it already, installing it would solve the issue.

---

Originally posted by [A_Hari](https://answers.ros.org/users/41462/a_hari/) with karma: 51 on 2019-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Red](https://answers.ros.org/users/41243/red/) on 2020-04-27**:
thank you your help :)